# How to use Doctrine Extensions in Api Platform

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony4, api-platform.com

I'm using [stofDoctrineExtensionsBundle](https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle) in a Symfony 4 project with Api Platform. I've **sluggable** and **timestampable** extensions actives. It works like a charm when I persist the entities manually, ie in the fixtures, but when I persist via the POST collectionOperations, it doesn't work, and said that those fields (slug, createdAt and updatedAt) are required.
I can't find a solution for this after several days.
Thank you very much (this is my first question here).

Comment: post your doctrine extension config, pls. I use Doctrine Extensions with Api-Platform and it works just fine

Comment: Can you post yours? I'd just remove this package from the project, but I still interested in usign it. Thank you very much.

Comment: Just stick to the docs, it should work like in a "normal" symfony app.
You can post your code, maybe i see something missing.

Comment: I have this issue also. Its sais :"Field createCardInput.createdAt of required type String! was not provided.Field createCardInput.updatedAt of required type String! was not provided." - I just use the use TimestampableEntity; Trait.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those fields should not be required.

The sluggable and timestampable extensions set their values onFlush, a doctrine event that calculates what has changed in your objects and runs the SQL queries to actually update the database. API Platform will make that happen at the WRITE stage, which is AFTER validation so validation will not see those values. Remove any assersions for those fields like `@Assert\NotBlank`, `@Assert\NotNull`.

If the fields are not nullable in the configuration of their mapping (for example `@ORM\Column()`) they will appear as required in the swagger, open api  or Hydra documentation generated by API Platform. Some clients, like the admin client and those from the client generator, use this documentation and will therefore make the inputs for those properties required.
Add the following annotations to the doc blocks of those properties:

```
* @ApiProperty(required=false)
```

This annotation requires near the top of the file:

```
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiProperty;
```